# How to update Hive partitioned columns to a new set of columns?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a dynamic partitioned managed table in Hive partitioned by `(country,state)`.
I wish to add one more column to these partitioned columns, say `(country,state,city)`.
I am thinking I may use `ALTER TABLE tab_nm DROP PARTITION old_partitions` and then use another `ALTER TABLE tab_nm ADD PARTITION..` to add new set of columns.
In one blog I read that a new table be created with latest partitions, load the data from the table with old partitions.  But then I do not wish to recreate the table as its a huge production table.
I still have not implemented the `ALTER TABLE..` since I am wondering that the `DROP PARTITION` may remove all the data in those partitions.
Please help.

Comment: Loading the data into a new table is definitely the right thing to do here. The data only needs to be duplicated for a short time.